# Найти и проставить id родителей

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс

Здравствуйте.
Имеется таблица вида:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Состоит она из двух таблиц - структура таблицы t1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

структура таблицы t2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

связь: t1.id = t2.value_id

В соответствии с полями 'uf_sap_code' и 'uf_sap_code_parent' необходимо найти родительские id и заполнить ими поле 'iblock_section_id'.
Пытаюсь написать рекурсию, но не получается:

```
function getCategory() {
    global $ibs;
    $query = $ibs->GetList(
        array('sort' => 'asc'),
        array('IBLOCK_ID' => 5),
        false,
        array('ID', 'NAME', 'IBLOCK_SECTION_ID', 'UF_SAP_CODE', 'UF_SAP_CODE_PARENT')
    );
    $result = array();
    while ($row = $query->Fetch()) {
        $result[$row["UF_SAP_CODE_PARENT"]][] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}

$category_arr = getCategory();

function getParentId($parent_id) {
    global $category_arr;
    if (isset($category_arr[$parent_id])) {
        foreach ($category_arr[$parent_id] as $value) {
            $id = $value["ID"];
            getParentId($value["UF_SAP_CODE"]);
        }    
        return $id;
    }
}
```

К сожалению с рекурсией не приходилось раньше сталкиваться. Насколько я понял, нужно условие углубления, но не могу сообразить. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну вообще-то в битриксе проставить родителей элементам/разделам можно сделать и через админку. Вручную лезть и править таблицу не самый хороший вариант. Зачем настолько все усложнять? Здесь рекурсия как мне кажется не нужна совершенно и можно ограничиться простым SQL запросом выполненным в данной таблице, который в цикле пройдет по всем записям у которых не пустой 'uf_sap_code_parent' и занесет его в 'iblock_section_id'.

Comment: дело в том, что эта таблица приведена для примера. На самом деле уровень вложенности больше 4... Этот код - часть самописного скрипта по загрузке csv-файла в инфоблок, поэтому средства битрикс не подходят.  По колхозному задачу я решил: сделал пять запросов подряд в цикле, но хотелось бы все-таки правильный код.

Comment: в 'iblock_section_id' нужно занести не значение 'uf_sap_code_parent', а соответствующий 'id', т.е., например, у id: 14,15,16,17 значением iblock_section_id должен быть id 13

Answer (score 1):

Если я все верно понял то здесь и правда можно обойтись без рекурсии, несмотря на то что связи в таблице могут быть.. вложенными многократно. Основная суть ведь в том чтобы в поле iblock_section_id проставить ID родителя? Думаю тут подошел бы один вот такой SQL запрос

```
UPDATE your_table t1 
JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.uf_sap_code_parent = t2.uf_sap_code
SET t1.iblock_section_id = t2.id
```

Вместо "your_table" имя вашей таблицы. Во время UPDATE'а мы попутно находим родителя (по полям uf_sap_code_parent и uf_sap_code) и извлекаем ID из него, который потом будет записан в iblock_section_id обновляемой таблицы.

Comment: спасибо за содействие! завтра попробую

Comment: хотел бы уточнить: t1 и t2 это две разные таблицы?

Comment: у меня id и iblock_section_id находятся в одной таблице, а uf_sap_code и uf_sap_code_parent в другой.

Comment: UPDATE b_iblock_section
            JOIN b_uts_iblock_5_section
            ON b_iblock_section.id = b_uts_iblock_5_section.VALUE_ID
            SET iblock_section_id = id
            WHERE uf_sap_code_parent = uf_sap_code

Comment: правильно ли я написал выше? при таком запросе ничего не происходит

Comment: Данный запрос для одной таблицы (я просто думал у вас одна, как та что вы показали). Если две, причем поля а uf_sap_code и uf_sap_code_parent в другой, то разумеется данный запрос не сработает. Нужно увидеть как выглядит одна и другая таблица и по каким полям они связаны, чтобы можно было что-то посоветовать..

Comment: структура первой таблицы: id | iblock_section_id | name|; структура второй таблицы: value_id | uf_sap_code | uf_sap_code_parent. Связь через id <=> value_id

Comment: нет вариантов ?